# In quantum money schemes, how is the list of serial numbers provided?

Tags: quantum-information

Public key quantum currency generally includes $k$ pairs ($S_\psi,\vert \psi\rangle)$ of classical information (bits) $S_\psi$ and quantum information (qubits) $\vert \psi\rangle$.

In many examples, $\vert \psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of some publicly known verification procedure $M$, and $S_\psi$ is some (efficiently computable) invariant of $M$.  A bank mints $k$ different coins by initially preparing qubits in a uniform superposition over the entire vector space of $M$, calculating (in ancillas) the invariant $S$, and measuring and recording the ancilla qubits as the serial number $S_\psi$.  That is, the eigenstates $\vert\psi\rangle$ are indexed by the serial number $S_\psi$.

The answer given in this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46079/quantum-money-where-not-even-the-bank-can-counterfeit) provides examples of quantum currencies, where *not even the bank* can produce counterfeit quantum money qubit states $\vert\psi\rangle$.  However, it's not been clear to me how the *serial numbers themselves* are stored - were they originally meant to be digitally signed?

> Is there a risk in having the bank publish a distributed list amongst users of the currency, in plaintext, of each of the $k$ serial numbers?

There might be an advantage in having a distributed database of plaintext serial numbers.  Users of the currency would know, or at least upper bound, precisely how much currency has been produced, and I don't think that the bank could overproduce without causing a devaluation.  If the bank were to mint more money, they would have to update their plaintext database, and users of the currency would recognize that the money they hold is deprecated.

Comment: The quantum money protocols don't specify exactly how the list of names is provided. Knowing the list shouldn't help anybody counterfeit the money, so I don't see any risk in having the bank publish a distributed list.